# Как получить информацию о входящем звонке Asterisk ARI

Tags: asterisk, ari

Подключимся к Asterisk при помощи websocket

```
var connection = new WebSocket("ws://ip:port/ari/events?app=qwer&subscribeAll=true&api_key=user:password")
```

Получаю все события

```
connection.onmessage = function(evt) {
      var msg = JSON.parse(evt.data);
      console.log(msg);
}
```

И результат разбираю в JSON

У меня не получается разобраться в [документации к ARI](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+13+REST+Data+Models#Asterisk13RESTDataModels-DeviceStateChanged)
Что такое канал и мост?

Как отловить событие входящего вызова и поднятии трубки оператора(для получения добавочного номера оператора)?

Прочитал много информации по AIR, но сделать выводы не удалось

Например есть [статья](https://habr.com/ru/post/311986/), но по всей видимости, она устарела

В статье при получении новых сообщений, ищет `event` со значением `incoming`

```
switch (msg.event) {
                case 'incoming':
```

Когда я получаю новые сообщения, в них нет `event`

Пример, какие приходят сообщения

```
{
  "type": "ChannelCreated",
  "timestamp": "2020-09-30T09:13:28.451+0500",
  "channel": {
    "id": "id",
    "name": "SIP/",
    "state": "Down",
    "caller": {
      "name": "",
      "number": ""
    },
    "connected": {
      "name": "",
      "number": ""
    },
    "accountcode": "",
    "dialplan": {
      "context": "incoming",
      "exten": "s",
      "priority": 1
    },
    "creationtime": "2020-09-30T09:13:28.451+0500",
    "language": "en"
  },
  "application": "qwer"
}
{
  "variable": "QUEUENAME",
  "value": "operators",
  "type": "ChannelVarset",
  "timestamp": "2020-09-30T09:14:01.628+0500",
  "channel": {
    "id": "id",
    "name": "SIP/",
    "state": "Up",
    "caller": {
      "name": "78008888888",
      "number": "+79099999999"
    },
    "connected": {
      "name": "",
      "number": ""
    },
    "accountcode": "",
    "dialplan": {
      "context": "incoming",
      "exten": "incom",
      "priority": 15
    },
    "creationtime": "2020-09-30T09:12:38.097+0500",
    "language": "ru"
  },
  "application": "qwer"
}
{
  "variable": "QUEUESRVLEVELPERF",
  "value": "0.0",
  "type": "ChannelVarset",
  "timestamp": "2020-09-30T09:14:01.629+0500",
  "channel": {
    "id": "id",
    "name": "SIP/",
    "state": "Up",
    "caller": {
      "name": "78008888888",
      "number": "+79099999999"
    },
    "connected": {
      "name": "",
      "number": ""
    },
    "accountcode": "",
    "dialplan": {
      "context": "incoming",
      "exten": "incom",
      "priority": 15
    },
    "creationtime": "2020-09-30T09:12:38.097+0500",
    "language": "ru"
  },
  "application": "qwer"
}
```